# How to make a diagram and get the exact intersection points at the same time?

Tags: plotting, manipulate

Here is the code. A part of the diagram is not a function.

```
sols3[x_, a_] = y /. Solve[x^2 + (y - a)^2 == 1, y];
sols2[x_, a_] = y /. Solve[y == a x^2, y];

Manipulate[{Plot[{sols3[x, a], sols2[x, a],
  PlotRange -> 20 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, PlotStyle -> Green, AspectRatio -> Automatic], 
  Solve[{x^2 + (y - a)^2 == 9 && y == a x^2}, {x, y}]}, {{a, 3}, -3,3, 0.1}]
```

*how can I get that done?*

Comment: What is `sols1`?

Comment: Sorry for that. I delete it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClearAll[sols2, sols3, intersections]
sols3[x_, a_] := y /. Solve[x^2 + (y - a)^2 == 9, y];
sols2[x_, a_] := y /. Solve[y == a x^2, y];
intersections[a_] := {x, y} /.Solve[{x^2 + (y - a)^2 == 9 && y == a x^2}, {x, y}, Reals]

Manipulate[Column@
  {Plot[Evaluate@Flatten[{sols3[x, a], sols2[x, a]}], {x, -20, 20}, 
     PlotRange -> 20 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, BaseStyle -> Thick, 
     Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[intersections[a]]}, 
     AspectRatio -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 300], 
   Column @ intersections[a]},
  {{a, 3}, -3, 3, 1/10}]
```

[image]